# is there a way to bundle files with an lsp-client in vscode

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, language-server-protocol

I'm following the guide at
https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/language-server-extension-guide to create an LSP Client for vscode (I already have a server, it's written in a different language).

I would like to know if it is possible to do either of these things:

1. bundle an external file with my VSIX file (bundled by the vsce tool) and then reference it in the command (e.g. bundling my server as a binary, thus not requiring user installation)
2. include a pre-check condition that would alert the user with a popup that they have not installed the server or some other system dependencies.

I do not have any experience with Typescript, so please be gentle with code snippets!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use vsix it should by default include the files in your main directory.

You can later access them for example using `path.join(context.extensionPath, "mybinary")`

At least it does work for us this way in https://github.com/scalameta/metals-vscode